# How to add unity project in a currently existing ios project?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, import, sdk

I have searched a lot about this. But all the answers suggest that, it is possible to add new files into unity(xcode) project but vice versa is not possible. Actually, my target is to create sdk which will be used in a cordova plugin. What should I do?

Comment: It is all-but impossible to do this.  If my studio was offered a three-month job to do this, we'd say no.  It's a nightmare, just as Nika says!

Answer (score 2):

To create an iOS sdk for unity you can create a library project in xCode and import the build to unity's `Assets/Plugins/iOS` folder. everything in here will automatically get included in xCode project generated by Unity.

And yes, it's very hard to include unity build in your own xcode project. There have been people begging for enlightenment to integrate Unity in another app but every time the threads are stranded beyond hope. Gibberish-gibberish... It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely frustrating but it is possible. It requires a lot of changes to the build settings and compiler settings as well as customizing the launch of Unity components.

Best place to start is to import the Classes, Libraries, and Data folders (if applicable). Data as a folder reference and not a group. I'm also assuming your Unity project output is similar to what I've been given. We've modified our main.m file to be a C++ file (main.mm) and added in the Unity initialization code. We also updated the UnityAppController.mm file to not run startUnity on launch.

If this is still something you're working on please feel free to contact me on Twitter (@Ruprect) and I can help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

In this repo: https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity you can find how to integrate Unity Project into Xcode Swift Project.