# Can I use xCode packe Unity3D files to be a framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I got a requirement from a customer who wants to integrate our AR/VR function, so we need to provide a plugin of AR/VR. The problem is coming, our AR/VR function uses Unity3D to demonstrate 3D models, so can I pack Unity3D files into a framework or .a file and provide some API, then the customer's developer calls those APIs to demonstrate 3D Models in their iOS App.

Comment: There are hacky and rather painful solutions to this, which I would not recommend:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865668/how-to-add-unity-project-in-a-currently-existing-ios-project
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075940/how-to-integrate-unity-into-a-swift-3-ios-project
https://the-nerd.be/2015/08/20/a-better-way-to-integrate-unity3d-within-a-native-ios-application/
https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5
https://bitbucket.org/jack_loverde/unity-5-vuforia-6-and-ios-native-integration

Comment: Yes, but I have to try these solutions anyway, Thanks.